# restrictions on what 大きな can modify

Tags: adjectives

I was having a conversation with a friend of mine who is also learning Japanese, and she used 大きなめんどくさい as a phrase today, which seemed off to me to use 大きい as a modifier on an adjective.  Can you use 大きい/な as an adverb to modify another adjective?  If so, are there restrictions around what sort of adjectives it can modify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No な form can modify an adjective.  The な ending creates what's called an *adnominal*, i.e. something that can only modify a nominal (noun).  This is a special kind of adjective -- while normal adjectives can be used to form predicates, such as "*that dog is **red***", adnominals can **only** be used to modify nouns, and **cannot** be used to form predicates.  大きい is a normal Japanese adjective, by this measure -- you can have 大きい犬 "*a **big** dog*", and you can have 犬が大きい "*the dog is **big***".  大きな is an adnominal, and only works one way -- you can have 大きな犬 "*a **big** dog*", but you can't have 犬が大きな "*the dog is a **big** ____*", because you **need** a noun after that な.

For adverbs, modifying verbs or adjectives, you'd have to use に instead of な, or the -く form of *-i* adjectives.

Your friend's sample phrase of 大きな面倒くさい could kinda work, if a noun came right after this phrase -- 大きな面倒くさい（何か） "*a big bothersome (something)*".  (Technically speaking, even that isn't quite right, and should probably be 大き**くて**面倒くさい（何か） instead.)  But if she intended for the 大きな to modify the 面倒くさい, the grammar just doesn't work that way.

**Addendum:**  If she was trying to say that something is *a big bother*, the grammatically correct way to say that is 大{おお}きな面倒{めんどう}.  The adjective 面倒{めんどう}くさい is literally 面倒{めんどう} "*a bother*" + くさい "*stinky, smelling of [something unpleasant]*".